# Java: Index json array inside a document in mongoDb

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I have a set of documents in mondoDB whose structure is as shown below

```
    "id":"documentId"
    {
      "listOfcards":
      [
         {
          "cardId":1,
          "drawingpath":
            [
              {
                 "strokeId":1,
                 "strokePoints":
                 [
                    {
                       "x":100
                       "y":100
                    },
                    {
                       "x":50
                       "y":10
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "strokeId":2,
                 "strokePoints":
                 [
                      ...
                 ]
              }

            ]
          },
          {
             "cardId":2,
             ...
          }
      ]
   }
```

I am writing a Java program to index this document. I have the following inputs with me

1. documentId
2. cardId
3. strokeId

If suppose my inputs were ("documentId",1,1), I want the following JSON object

```
"strokePoints":
[
   {
      "x":100
      "y":100
   },
   {
      "x":50
      "y":10
   }      
]
```

In particular, for a given document, a given cardID and a given stroke ID, I want to get the min value of "x" and "y" for that stroke. I have a current implementation in which I have a loop to iterate through a list of card objects, and then an inner loop to iterate through a list of strokes inside that card and another inner loop to iterate through the points on that stroke and then find the min values of x and y. I want to know if there is any other method in which I can index the database to directly get that specific object or just the min values.

Answer (score 0):

Although they may not be a tool to do the calculation (min x & y) it definitely worth to have a look at this JSON to JSON transformer https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt. This tool could help you transform the MongoDB document into something more suitable to work with.

Second approach could be to use dynamic JVM languages (like Groovy) to the JSON manipulation. They have far better support for traversing JSONs (see http://www.groovy-lang.org/json.html) and in case of Groovy it compilers straight into Java bytecode.